# tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc - what value represents my AUC

Tags: python, tensorflow, auc

I'm trying to find the AUC value using [tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_auc). This issue is that after each epoch, I'm having AUC values as follows:

```
(0.0, 0.37472612)
(0.0, 0.57414174)
(0.0, 0.5894814)
...
```

If I understood the documentation correctly, the first value (i.e. 0.0) represents the `auc`, and the second value represents `update_op`.

Which value is actually representing the AUC value after each epoch in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The metrics package has a unique way of functioning. The first value in this case is the AUC, the second value you don't need to ever look at, you just need to run the OP to update the value over multiple batches (multiple calls to `sess.run`.

The reason for this approach is that if you were to compute just AUC, that would work fine within one call to `sess.run`, but if you have to compute AUC over a dataset that is too large to process in one call to `sess.run` you'll have to save some aggregate variables in order to compute a final AUC at the end of all the batches (this is what the metrics package does).

The solution is the `update_op`. When you run the `update_op` for each batch, over multiple batches, it accumulates what it needs to compute the AUC. At any time you can ask for the computed value of the AUC (your first property) and you will get a computation based on the current variables being managed by the `update_op` (without changing the value). If you're getting all 0's I guess you just haven't been running the `update_op`. I'm not sure what value I'd expect from the `update_op` itself (the second value you are showing), it should be a group of OPs I expect, so I don't know how to interpret that exactly.